# Read SVG file. IHTMLElement getAttribute returns System.__ComObject

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, svg, webbrowser-control

I try to manage SVG file from System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.
But when I called `element.getAttribute([Name], 0)` it returns `System.__ComObject`.
And I don't know what interface need for `System.__ComObject`.

SVG

```
<g id="MovieClip1" transform="matrix( 0.670867919921875, 0, 0, 0.5272674560546875, 150,100) "></g>
```

C#

```
  var element = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("MovieClip1").DomElement as IHTMLElement;
  var g = element.getAttribute("transform", 0); // System.__ComObject
```

Is it possible manage SVG file from C# without HTML page and JS?

It's work for an HTML page.

```
    <body>
    <object id="ExampleFla" width="400" height="300" type="image/svg+xml" data="ExampleFla.svg">
    </object>
    <script> 
    var svg = document.getElementById("ExampleFla");
    var svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
    var group = svgDoc.getElementById("MovieClip1");
    var value = group.getAttributeNS(null,"transform");
    <script> 
    </body>
```